# urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError HubSpot API / LlamaHub integration error

Tags: python, hubspot

I am trying to connect with HubSpot:

either by LlamaHub:
https://llama-hub-ui.vercel.app/l/hubspot

or HubSpot API:

```
from hubspot import HubSpot

api_client = HubSpot(access_token=hub_api)

api_client = HubSpot()
api_client.access_token = hub_api
print("ok")


from hubspot.crm.contacts import ApiException

try:
    contact_fetched = api_client.crm.contacts.basic_api.get_by_id('contact_id')
    print(contact_fetched)
except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when requesting contact by id: %s\n" % e)
```

Both are giving me the same error:

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.hubapi.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /crm/v3/objects/contacts/contact_id (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1002)')))
```